# Is there a way to make axis2 recognise @XmlElement annotations?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

From my web service method I am returning an object of a class that contains a number of @XmlElement and other @Xml annotations to control the names of items in the xml. Axis2 happily bundles it all up in a SOAP response but completely ignores the @Xml annotations. Is there a way to make Axis2 recognise the annotations?